# ExtJS combobox: the values loaded but doesn't show

Tags: extjs

This my code to add combobox in extjs version 2.2 ..... the data is loaded and showed empty rows and when select any row it get the right item and i want to align the label to left

Thanks in advance

Ext.onReady(function(){

```
var relationValues = new Ext.data.Store({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['DKEY', 'NAME_AR', 'NAME_EN'],
        root: 'rows'
    }),
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'LoadRelation'
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});

var userForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

    standardSubmit: true,

    frame:true,
    title: 'User Information',
    width: 350,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combo',
            name: 'relation',
            fieldLabel: 'Relation',
            mode: 'local',
            store: relationValues,
            displayField:'NAME_EN',
            valueField: 'DKEY',
            //anchor: '100%',
            listeners: {
                select: function(f,r,i){
                    console.log(r);
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Insert',
        handler: function() {
            userForm.getForm().getEl().dom.action = 'login';
            userForm.getForm().getEl().dom.method = 'POST';
            userForm.getForm().submit();
        }
    },{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            userForm.getForm().reset();
        }
    }]
});
userForm.render('mydiv');
```

});

Comment: When selecting one of the value-less items, do you get the log message in the console, and does the record include a value in NAME_EN? Been a while since I coded ExtJs 2, but since you are loading from a store, should not mode be set to 'remote'?

Comment: I solved including my js in my jsp and pass the var, thanks anyway.